# Flying from Ibiza to Dublin on route to New York City

Tags: customs-and-immigration, dub

We will be on holiday in Ibiza and before we book our return flight back to NY we're wondering whether to fly from Dublin rather than a London airport.

Will we then be able to go through Immigration there and not in the US when we land?

Comment: It may dramatically alter your ticket price, and your comfort level; as far as I can tell only Ryanair has nonstop flights IBZ-DUB. That means separate tickets and transferring your bags in Dublin, which makes your transit there much more complicated. Where are you trying to go in the US? Is preclearance important enough to endure a Ryanair flight, extra airport inconvenience, possibly missing a flight and being on the hook for that, and possibly pay a lot more overall?

Comment: I'd suggest you look at booking two tickets - Ibiza to Dublin, then an entirely separate Dublin-USA one. You need to leave plenty of time (overnight is best), but you'll likely save a lot of money vs a London ticket as Dublin-USA flights *tend* to be quite a bit cheaper than London-USA ones

Comment: Oh, also...Ryanair's IBZ-DUB nonstop is a seasonal route that only starts in April, so if your holiday is before then, that's right out.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it certainly is possible to construct an itinerary via Dublin on the way back to the US. However, none of the major alliance carriers nor their interline feeders operate a direct service on Dublin-Ibiza; therefore it will involve another stop at an intermediate point in Europe (where will depend on which airline alliance you use). Because of the way most transatlantic fares are now structured, this should not materially affect the ticket price.

Most of the NYC terminals now have the new "Automatic Passport Control" [APC] machines and I have found (as a non-US Passport holder) that entry times have been significantly reduced.

I am not sure it is worth a detour through Dublin purely to avail yourself of pre-clearance.